# Non-italicized enumerated list inside theorem?

Tags: enumerate, theorems

I want not-to-italicized an enumerated list within the theorem environment. Any help in getting this done is much appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{thm}
    Hello everyone
    \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{thm}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: The entire (text of the) list or just the labels ((i), (ii) etc.)?

Comment: @moewe, the question is for the latter.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
  Hello everyone
  \begin{enumerate}[\normalfont(i)]
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
  \end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, for the case of `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
  Hello everyone
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\normalfont(\roman*)]
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
  \end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me how to get it done under \usepackage{enumitem} as well.

Comment: @Fib1123 -- I added another case for `enumitem`.

Comment: It's better to use two keys: `[label=(\roman*), font=\normalfont]`, or  `[label=(i), font=\normalfont]]` if enumitem is loaded with option `shortlabels`.